Using a custom Union type hint is not allowed by typechecker
I am working on a python project where an interface can accept objects of several types (from different packages) that all share the same underlying structure and methods. I want to make this type union explicit to be warned in case an unspecified type would be provided instead of one of the few expected ones.
My code would look like something like this.
from package1 import Type1 
from package2 import Type2
from package3 import Type3

MY_CUSTOM_TYPE = Type1 | Type2 | Type3

def process(x: MY_CUSTOM_TYPE):
    do stuff...

But for some reason Pylance complains about x: MY_CUSTOM_TYPE, stating the following: "Variable not allowed in type expression." Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

If Type1, Type2 and Type3 are all types, then MY_CUSTOM_TYPE should have been valid as a type. Please provide a [mre].

Thanks for your answer @InSync. Indeed, I cannot reproduce it on PyRight playground either with a minimal example. I will continue searching and update the post once I know more.

So, I figured out part of the solution.
It turns out that one of the types I am using is XGBClassifier (from the xgboost library), which for some obscure reason transforms "type alias" into "UnionType" when it is included in a union.
CUSTOM_TYPE_1 = Type1 | Type2 -> type alias
CUSTOM_TYPE_2 = Type1 | Type 2 | XGBClassifier -> constant UnionType
I have no idea why though.

Why not use the built-in Union type?

I think as of python 3.10+ both formulations are equivalent (Union[type1, type2] and type1 | type2)
